# Python "is" v/s "=" weird behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, `x is y` returns true if the two sides evaluate to the same object; that is, it checks pointer equality. Now I tried something like this:

```
>>>a = 2  
>>>a is 2  
True
```

However..

```
>>>a = 9203409249024  
>>>a is 9203409249024  
False
```

Why this difference in behavior?

Comment: This is an optimization in Cpython (and perhaps some others) and has been answered here before... I'll look for the dupe...

Answer (score 0):

Python (and other languages) cache small numbers in memory, so that multiple variables that have the value (for example) 2 will point to the same location in memory (and, hence, `is` returns `True`).